# Why do developers find ES6's new features syntactic sugar?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, es6-modules, es6-class

ES6 has lots of new features such as classes, lambda expressions and so on. I wonder why these features are considered syntactic sugar? If it is a syntactic sugar then what needs to be done in order not call them "syntactic sugar", I mean real implementation?

Comment: What do you mean by syntactic sugar? I've never heard that expression

Comment: [What is the difference between “Syntax” and “Syntactic Sugar”](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194007/what-is-the-difference-between-syntax-and-syntactic-sugar)

Comment: It's syntax sugar because they do the same, but look cleaner.

Comment: Note that the term "syntactic sugar" doesn't automatically imply that something is bad. It could often be the opposite (as it often makes things easier to write and read).

Comment: It's a term that means that a feature is implemented in a manner so that is more succinct or cleaner to write. You can typically do these things without the "syntactic sugar". In a compiled language syntactic sugar is typically stripped out. In a pre-compiled language the "sugar" may be removed for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

They *are* real implementation. "Syntactic sugar" just means that you **could** do those things without the new feature, it's just a lot more of a pain. Some of the new things in ES2015+ fall into that category (including `class` and arrow functions, as you mentioned). Others do not (`Proxy`, `WeakMap`, `Reflect.construct` as it relates to `Error` and `Array` [at least]); you can't do those things without the new feature behind them.

"Syntactic sugar" isn't pejorative. It's just descriptive.

If you follow the [es-discuss mailing list](https://mail.mozilla.org/listinfo/es-discuss), you'll see that a lot of syntactic sugar doesn't make it to the proposal stage because it isn't sweet enough. ;-) But sometimes — and `class` and arrow functions are both good examples — the sugar is well-worth it.